# Use resolveActivity To Check if Intent Can Be Handled

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-11

I am trying to disable the camera launch button in my app if the camera intent cannot be handled by the device. I am targeting Android R (11). The code that I have so far is this

```
  val packageManager: PackageManager = requireActivity().packageManager

  val captureImage = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
  if (captureImage.resolveActivity(packageManager) == null) {
    isEnabled = false
  }
```

The issue that I am having is that when I implement this code the camera launch button is always disabled even on devices that support it. I am not sure why it is doing this other than that maybe I need to add [`package-visibility`](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) into the manifest file but I am unsure how that all works as the documentation isn't the best when it comes to examples. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add queries like this in your manifiest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />

        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

     <application
      ...
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to explain the queries children?

Comment: Umm.. for any android dev they are very clear. No need to explain which is already self-explanatory and I think it is out of the scope of this question.

Comment: What would be the intent for access to contacts?

Comment: There are no queries for contacts it's permission. So you would need a read contacts permission.